# Calling java class under src/test from pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I know that we can call a java class from maven using the exec plugin and specifying the class in the mainClass tag.  However this seems to work only when the java class is under src/main/java. 
Unfortunately, I have my mainClass under src/test/java.  Is there a way I can call this class under test.  PS. I did try the "classpathScope" but didn't help.

Comment: Have you ever tried to make a real unit test from it and let be calling by maven during the test phase?

Comment: I agree with khmarbaise. You should think about writing a real unit test. Otherwise you could try to move this class to a separate module and put it into the directory src/main/java. In your module you can depend on the test module with scope test. In this case the classpathScope may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test classes are by definition only used during tests and are never part of the final package/JAR. Thus you cannot use them as a `Main-Class`.

If you really want to, you can probably copy (using `antrun-plugin`) compiled `Main` class from `target/test-classes` to `target/classes` before packaging but after `test-compile` phase.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to solve my problem :) though I didnt use the ant-plugin for that instead I used the maven-resources-plugin.